# How do I use both the ES6 loader and the brfs transform in webpack?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, browserify, babeljs

I have a big webpack generated ui written in ES6 and I want to add an npm module that uses fs.readFileSync() named lumenize. The package is normally built with browserify. I'm having trouble configuring webpack to use bfrs from inside of ES6 code.

I've tried this configuration:

```
loaders: [
  "transform?brfs",
  "babel-loader"
],
```

and reversed the order, but neither works.

I've thought of trying to import the browserified version of the package, but that browserified version exposes a global polyfill for require() for use directly in the browser. I understand that's a no-no for webpack. Is that true? I could fork the project and remove that global exposure, but help with that configuration would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put `transform` in the `postLoaders` section as it was described in transform-loader Readme:

```
postLoaders: [
  {
    loader: "transform?brfs"
  }
],
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: "babel"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still no joy. It turns out the readFileSync call is not in the dependency. It's in a dependency of the dependency. So, I'm wondering if that's messing it up. I've created a workaround by forking that dependency and removing the parts I don't need (for now at least). It just so happens that's where the readFileSync call is. So, I'm good for now.

Comment: Do you have any `exclude` options set? Maybe transform just isn't executed for that file. Also, you may encounter with that issue: https://github.com/webpack/transform-loader/issues/6